# Eclipse won't run app because it says I have errors but I have no errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run an android project on eclipse but every time I try this particular project it gives me the message,

> "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your
>   application."

I know the problem isn't with the emulator because I can run other projects efficiently.

I have no errors underlined anywhere in any of my project files.
I even tried removing what I had been working on at the time and leaving only what I had the day before.
I tried manually deleting the .android, r.java, and bin files but none of those solutions worked. When I pull up my properties the build path shows no errors. No errors show up in my LogCat.

I need a solution.

This is a copy of my manifest because I know I will be asked to check it.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.com.proto1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".mainj"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mainj" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Infoactive"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INFOSCREEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check the problems tab in Eclipse

Comment: Also, try doing Project -> Clean

Comment: I tried cleaning and restarting eclipse and my computer several times already: Sorry I meant to say that originally but forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This unusual behavior is generally observed when there is something wrong in the xml files.
  When you cant find an error elsewhere go to `Window - > show view - > Problems`, you might find something there.
- if that doesnt work, right click on the files, you recently changed , in the navigator - > Compare with - > local history , replace files with their previous versions and rebuild. Iterate the process until your project is error free.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have found an error that says The project was not built because it depends on xxxxxx which has build path errors.

Comment: google the error and hope someone else would have had that problem and posted a solution. That's the way to go :-)

Comment: I resolved the error without looking it up. I just removed the build path dependency in my project properties. Thanks for the help.